# unable to dynamically set height of div

Tags: javascript, jquery, magento

I want to dynamically resize one of my divs to take the height of the viewport using the following javascript

```
<script>
var applyMapContainerHeight = function() {
var wH = window.screen.height;
wH = parseInt(wH) + 'px';
$("#main-container-col2-rt-layout").css('height',wH);
console.log(wH);
 };

$(document).ready(function() {
   applyMapContainerHeight();
});
</script>
```

My div is coded as:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
<div class="page">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
    <div id="main-container-col2-rt-layout" class="main-container col2-   right-layout">
        <div class="main">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>
...........
```

This is a magento page for my e-commerce site. Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from `vm` and `vh` `<length>` datatypes, I see that your code works!

```
<style>
body {
    margin: 0; padding: 0;
}
.main-container {
    background: red;
}
</style>
<body>
<div class="wrapper">
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('global_notices') ?>
<div class="page">
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('header') ?>
    <div id="main-container-col2-rt-layout" class="main-container col2-   right-layout">
        <div class="main">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('breadcrumbs') ?>

</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<script>
var applyMapContainerHeight = function() {
var wH = window.screen.height;
wH = parseInt(wH) + 'px';
document.getElementById("main-container-col2-rt-layout").style.height = wH;
console.log(wH);
 };

(function() {
   applyMapContainerHeight();
})();
</script>
</body>
```

Your question was somehow unclear about what the problem really was, but if the problem is you want `wrapper` and `page` not to have a white background, then the solution is to apply dynamic width to the highest div element (i mean the grandpa i.e. `wrapper`).

Comment: you are right... the code works standalone... I need to find out why was it not working when in php/magento...

Comment: @coderatlarge maybe php echos some code that contains styling that  positions elements (absolute, relative) which causes the page to look unordered or unarranged. Maybe its a good idea to post the executed html code! (i mean after php _cooked_ the page).

Answer (score 0):

Css has units specifically for this:

**vh and vw**

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfbrdomb/show

```
div.red {
    height: 100vh;
    width: 100vw;
    background-color: red;
}
```